# ios-json array parsing issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

I have problem with this json data:

```
{"return":"{\"productsList\":
[{\"BrandUID\":0,\"BrandName\":\"KAIREE\",\"ProductUID\":213,\"ProductName\":\"ANARKALI NET 
WITH BANARASI 
INNER\",\"Address\":\"\",\"Email\":\"\",\"Phone\":\"\",\"Price\":\"15000.00\",\"MainImage\":
\"http:\\\/\\\/tagin.xspl.in:8888\\\/images\\\/medium\\\/IMG_2635.JPG\",\"TagCount\":0},
{\"BrandUID\":0,\"BrandName\":\"KAIREE\",\"ProductUID\":245,\"ProductName\":\"SILK CHOODIDAR
 SUIT\",\"Address\":\"\",\"Email\":\"\",\"Phone\":\"\",\"Price\":\"5195.00\",\"MainImage\":\
"http:\\\/\\\/tagin.xspl.in:8888\\\/images\\\/medium\\\/IMG_2696.JPG\",\"TagCount\":0},
{\"BrandUID\":0,\"BrandName\":\"ROOP SANGAM\",\"ProductUID\":124,\"ProductName\":\"KOTA 
SILK\",\"Address\":\"\",\"Email\":\"\",\"Phone\":\"\",\"Price\":\"1050.00\",\"MainImage\":\"
http:\\\/\\\/tagin.xspl.in:8888\\\/images\\\/medium\\\/DSC_0181.JPG\",\"TagCount\":0}]}"}
```

can please some help me...I want array of image urls i.e of keys `MainImage`.

How can I do it using `NSJSONSerialization`

Comment: you can try with taking some dictionaries and arrays that might give you the crashes but from that crashes you came to know that you need to use array or dictionary this is how you can go for and don't forgot to log the response after every successful step.

Comment: You can do it using NSJSONSerialization.  There are many examples here, if you bother to look.

Comment: I have downvote because this is very basic and you have not shown what you have tried and what problem u face in your code.

Comment: @CRDave: I think you have not seen the my **json format.**

Comment: Your json string contain extra "\" which you can remove very easily.

Comment: What you want to know? Whether the json is valid or want to get the value for the key "MainImage"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like "nested JSON": the value of the "return" key is a string that itself
contains a complete JSON object. In that case you have to de-serialize twice,
something like this:

```
NSData *jsonData = ... // your JSON data
NSError *error;

NSDictionary *outerObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error: &error];

NSData *innerJson = [outerObject[@"return"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *innerObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:innerJson options:0 error:&error];
```

And now you can access the inner JSON object, for example:

```
NSArray *productsList = innerObject[@"productsList"];
NSArray *mainImages = [productsList valueForKey:@"MainImage"];
```

Comment: inner json looks like array

Comment: yes you are right @Martin its a nested JOSN. I checked it in JSON validator.@Pritam Parse it twice.

Comment: @preetam: Yes, but I could not see that immediately from your data :-) - Answer updated.

Comment: @MartinR:last line giving me error: expected method to read array element not found on type nsdictionary

Comment: @preetam: See updated answer. (You should inspect the objects, check if it is an array or dictionary, and then apply the appropriate methods. I tried to solve your *main problem*, which is the nested JSON. You should be able to figure out the rest with these examples.)

Comment: @MartinR: problem was in second key "productList" that you were not using...thanks solved now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 id mainDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&parseError];
```

***Note:- here data is your response coming from server.***

Now when you saw carefully above **JSON** data, the things wrapped inside *{*(curly bracket) are in the form of dictionary. And the things that are wrapped inside *[*(square bracket)are in the form of array.

So you can parse your data by following code,as our data is in maindict

```
NSArray *array = [[maindict valueForKey:@"return"]valueForKey:@"productsList"]];
```

Now when you print array you will get 3 elements in array.

Comment: thanks for reply,I am getting this error::: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key productsList.'

Comment: can you send me url link you are hitting

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your JSON data is valid?
For example, this is valid JSON

```
{"\"key\"": "value"}
```

This is not:

```
{\"key\": "value"}
```

Comment: yah..! thats why I am asking here...

Answer (score 0):

Please check the JSON data, i have modified, with extra "}"

```
{
"productsList": [
    {
        "BrandUID": 0,
        "BrandName": "KAIREE",
        "ProductUID": 213,
        "ProductName": "ANARKALINETWITHBANARASIINNER",
        "Address": "",
        "Email": "",
        "Phone": "",
        "Price": "15000.00",
        "MainImage": "http: //tagin.xspl.in: 8888/images/medium/IMG_2635.JPG",
        "TagCount": 0
    },
    {
        "BrandUID": 0,
        "BrandName": "KAIREE",
        "ProductUID": 245,
        "ProductName": "SILKCHOODIDARSUIT",
        "Address": "",
        "Email": "",
        "Phone": "",
        "Price": "5195.00",
        "MainImage": "http: //tagin.xspl.in: 8888/images/medium/IMG_2696.JPG",
        "TagCount": 0
    },
    {
        "BrandUID": 0,
        "BrandName": "ROOPSANGAM",
        "ProductUID": 124,
        "ProductName": "KOTASILK",
        "Address": "",
        "Email": "",
        "Phone": "",
        "Price": "1050.00",
        "MainImage": "http: //tagin.xspl.in: 8888/images/medium/DSC_0181.JPG",
        "TagCout": 0
    }
]
```

}